# AI / ML powered email chaser

Tags: email, email-client, gmail

I imagine that there is/ should be a tool that I can copy in to emails that checks if they get responded to in an appropriate amount of time.

For example: cc: 2days@followup.myemail
Then if you don't get a response (either copied to that email, or just in your inbox) it sends a follow up 2 business days later.

I use gmail - but any email software could do this easily.
The email could come from the follow up bot, or from me.
It could be written by some AI, or just be a "bump" with nothing more in the body but the previous email. Sent at a different time, maybe around the time the message was read (if known/ could be added to tool as a function)

Thoughts? Is it out there?
I could achieve it with a label in Gmail and scripts pretty easily I think.
ie. label "2 days" and trigger is set to check that label every 10 minutes.
If 2 days from sent date has past, and no reply, or another email from me sent - send "reply all" and "bump" in body.

I would prefer a more professional product though, with a team thinking stuff up that I haven't thought about.